# "Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /adCampaignGroups" while call the LinkedIn API with all existing permissions

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm just trying to get all the campaign groups linked to an ad account via the https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search API using Postman. But I get a 403 error "**Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /adCampaignGroups**".

I know I need the "**r_ads**" and "**rw_ads**" permissions, but I tried to generate an access_token with **all permissions**, and it still doesn't work.

My exact API call : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search.account.values=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:999999999
=> "999999999" is replaced by the real id of my ad account whose access-token is linked to a LinkedIn admin account (ACCOUNT_BILLING_ADMIN)

I don't understand how a token that has all the permissions, and an application that has all the LinkedIn products can receive a 403 code in this case

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with the LinkedIn API. Their API documentation isn't completely up to date nor is it clear.

Our requests worked when we used the endpoints listed in the app. Make sure that when your app is still in a Development tier, that you link an existing ad account that you're an admin of to the app.

You can then use the endpoints like this:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2

This worked for us.

Comment: Thanks. This route works for me : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search&search.account.values[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:999999999

Doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/adcampaigngroups?view=li-lms-2022-07